# Android Studio : error: illegal start of type homework

Tags: java, android-studio

Homework, im pretty new to Android Studio and Java.

Please write in layman's terms! I get an error when trying to build the code.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == btnCredits) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        alert.setTitle("Made by");

        alert.setMessage("REDACTED" + "\nMGMS | CSE\n09/12/2019");

        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
           Object id;
            ArraySet inv;

                int gold = 0;

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < inv.size(); ++i) {
                    if (inv.getClass(i).name.equals("Gold")) {
                        gold++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    sb.append("\n");
                    sb.append(inv.getClass(i).name);

                }
                sb.append("\n" + gold + "Gold\n");

        Dialog dialog;
        dialog.setMessage(sb.toString());
                dialog.setTitle("Inventory");
                dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE("OK", (alert), id);
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
                ;
                dialog.show();
            }
        }); // This line is the highlighted problem
```

(error: illegal start of type) This is the error I get when trying to build but when I inspect the code there are only warnings, and I've been told you can ignore warnings but not errors.

If you see anything else that could be improved in the code, please tell me and explain if you can. Thank you for your time and patience!

Comment: Could you please add the full error message and tell us when exactly the error occurs?

Comment: what is that code block supposed to do there? you can't just create a block mid-method.